# Using aggregate with custom function (using values based on another column)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a table that is something like this.

```
benchmark    technqiue       stat            value

perlbench   compression encoding_Zero               10
perlbench   compression encoding_Repeated_Values    20
perlbench   compression encoding_Base8_1            30
perlbench   compression encoding_Base8_2            40
perlbench   compression encoding_Base8_4            50
perlbench   compression encoding_Base4_1            60
perlbench   compression encoding_Base4_2            70
perlbench   compression encoding_Base2_1            80
perlbench   compression encoding_Uncompressed       90
```

There are other combinations of benchmarks and techniques but I'm keeping it simple.

I want for every combination of benchmark and technique to get the values of every encoding and multiply each one of them with a different number and then sum their result. Then I want to create a new row for that value with a new stat name.

The function is something like this: compressed_size = (10*1 + 20*8 + 30*16 + ... + 90*64)

I have seen other questions about using aggregate with custom functions, but I'm not sure how to distinguish between each value based on its relation with what type of stat it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to apply a different multiplier for every stat in your table?

This sounds like an application for [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html):

```
library(dplyr)

df_summary <- df %>%
  mutate(
    stat_multiplier = case_when(
      stat == 'encoding_Zero' ~ 1,
      stat == 'encoding_Repeated_Values' ~ 8,
      stat == 'encoding_Base8_1' ~ 16,
      [...],
      stat == 'encoding_Uncompressed' ~ 64,
      TRUE ~ 1 # if none of the above is true, this would keep the value as-is instead of returning a NA
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(benchmark, technique) %>%
  summarise(
     compressed_size = sum(value * stat_multiplier, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function which increments the value to multiply and use `aggregate`

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
   sum(x * c(1, seq_along(x[-1]) * length(x[-1])))
}

aggregate(value~benchmark + technqiue, df, apply_fun)

#  benchmark   technqiue value
#1 perlbench compression 19210
```

The function can also be used with `dplyr` or `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(benchmark, technqiue) %>%  summarise(total = apply_fun(value))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (total = apply_fun(value)), .(benchmark, technqiue)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(benchmark = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "perlbench", class = "factor"), technqiue = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "compression", class = "factor"), 
stat = structure(c(9L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L), 
.Label = c("encoding_Base2_1", "encoding_Base4_1", "encoding_Base4_2",
"encoding_Base8_1", "encoding_Base8_2", "encoding_Base8_4", 
"encoding_Repeated_Values", "encoding_Uncompressed", "encoding_Zero"),
class = "factor"), value = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```